# Failed to install ionic cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm getting these errors when trying to run `sudo npm install -g ionic cordova`

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/usr/local/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic

> fsevents@1.2.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.3 and node@9.2.1 (node-v59 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v59-darwin-x64' 
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.9.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ cordova@8.0.0
+ ionic@3.20.0
updated 2 packages in 13.581s
```

I've tried updating/installing node-gyp and fixing permissions issues on node_modules.

Answer (score 3):

I think below command should fix your issue:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

For more information please check this thread: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17268

Answer (score 1):

Try "sudo npm install -g ionic cordova"

Answer (score 0):

These commands worked for me:

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

[Original post](https://github.com/jansmolders86/mediacenterjs/issues/191)